# simulate GPS location in Symbian S60

Tags: gps, symbian, nokia, s60, s60-3rd-edition

Is there a way to simulate the GPS location in Symbian ? I know that 'Simulation PSY' Tools aids in simulating GPS location in Symbian. But i am looking for more specific application that runs within the Symbian Emulator/Device that aids me to set different GPS location (faking GPS location)

Answer (score 0):

You can set different files with position data in NMEA format to be used by "Simulation PSY".
I was using [NMEAXmit](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/NMEAXmit_-_a_NMEA_dumper_for_S60_3rd_Edition) application to record data in that format.

Not sure if it helps to you, but Qt emulator in Nokia Qt Sdk has the feature you need, one can easily set position there.

Answer (score 0):

In the S60 5th emulator, from the Windows menu of the emulator, select Tools > Utilities > Route. Here at least you can simulate position changing along a complex route.